# How to use ST_Contains() with ST_ClusterWithin()

Tags: postgis, extents, centroids, spatial-cluster

I need to write a spatial query which will return `centroids` of clusters which are within a bounding box or polygon.

The query I have now is:

```
SELECT
    ST_NumGeometries(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(ST_PointFromText(centroid), 10))) AS venueCount,
    ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(ST_PointFromText(centroid), 10)))) AS clusterCentroid
FROM venue_locations
WHERE ST_MakeEnvelope (...) ~ ST_Centroid(unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(ST_PointFromText(centroid), 10)));
```

This, however, gives me the error:

`ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE`

If I replace `WHERE` with `HAVING`, I get the following error:

`ERROR: argument of HAVING must not return a set`

How can I write this to be efficient for large databases?

EDIT: to clear up any confusion, what I am trying to accomplish it to get clustered points from the database which are in a specific extent.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do with the WHERE clause. The clustering algorithms implicitly do that for, so you are repeating logic (as well as returning a set from the WHERE, as the query planner is telling you.

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear to me what you are trying to do here, but if you need to do an unnest, you are better off using ST_ClusterDBScan if you have PostGIS 2.3+.
I'm also not clear why you have two calls to ST_ClusterWithin each with different distance.

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html

```
WITH c AS (SELECT ST_ClusterDBScan(centroid,100,10) AS cluster_num, vl.geom
    FROM venue_locations AS vl
)
SELECT COUNT(c.geom), cluster_num, ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(c.geom)) AS mgeom
FROM c
GROUP BY cluster_num
HAVING ST_MakeEnvelope (...) && ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(c.geom)) ;
```

You might also want to consider using ST_GeometricMedian instead of ST_Centroid. ST_GeometricMedian is also new in PostGIS 2.3

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometricMedian.html

Comment: The two different distances are a copying mistake. I’m going to edit the question to make it more clear what I am trying to do.